# Styling DatePicker ArrowButton in Javafx

Tags: javafx, javafx-11, javafx-css, javafx-datepicker

[How to achieve the following style for Datepicker Arrow Button?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SOIm.png)

[I am able to Achieve the following Style For Arrow Button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFDMt.png)

Below Css is used for achieving the above style

```
.date-picker > .arrow-button > .arrow {
   -fx-opacity:0;
}

.date-picker > .arrow-button {
    -fx-background-image:url("/com/ispiro/ui/assets/img/datepicker.png")
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -fx-background-position: center center;
    -fx-background-color:#1079D8;
    
   
}
```

Comment: I'm unclear what the question is here.

Comment: @James_D have edited the images in question. I want to have padding between the borders of datepicker and arrow button background.